# how to custom seo url with htaccess or php

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I have an URL

```
http://www.domain.com/song.php?id=MkJoY2JyX3FWY2Q3b09nUFlZTkdDQT09
```

And i want to change it to:

```
domain.com/song/MkJoY2JyX3FWY2Q3b09nUFlZTkdDQT09?
```

What is needed? Can anyone help me solve my problem??

Comment: You could show some code. It should help to understand Your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write following code on your .htaccess file make sure mode rewrite rule is enable on your httpd.conf file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^song/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ song.php?id=$1;
```